# How to get a decent score with steam in Railworks 2 career mode?

Tags: railworks-2

I've been working my way through the Railworks 2 career scenarios, but the steam ones are proving near impossible (specifically, the Bath and Templecombe route).

The train can only manage about 15 mph because of steep inclines, and I end up at least 10 minutes late (or worse) giving a huge negative score. I've seen other scores posted that are about +2,000 where the best I can managed is -17,000. I don't have the same problems with the diesel/electric trains, so I think I'm missing some vital piece of knowledge about running the steam engine and improving its performance.

Comment: thx @Shaun for the retag

Answer (score 2):

it sounds like you are still getting to grips with driving steam locomotives. If you have the latest RailWorks free update from Steam, you should now have a steam driving tutorial available from the front screen in RailWorks 2. That will help you understand how to use the steam reverser and regulator to best effect and maintain power up inclines. Good luck!

Comment: sounds good - i'll have a look and run through the tutorial

Comment: Well, I went through the tutorial (which actually takes you on the same route as the career scenario) - and learnt about the 'running' setting for the brakes and balancing the regulator/reverser to keep steam pressure up - but I still couldn't make it to the first station in anywhere like a reasonable time (I think I was about 5-10 minutes late again)